# High priority GCM message in Android with PHP?

Tags: android, json, google-cloud-messaging

My question is.. ¿How can I change my GCM priority like google said? I was reading **Google Developers** when I saw that;

> Setting the priority of a message
>
> You have two options for assigning delivery priority to downstream messages: normal and high priority. Delivery of high and normal priority messages works like this:
>
> **High priority:** GCM attempts to deliver high priority messages immediately, allowing the GCM service to wake a sleeping device when possible and open a network connection to your app server. Apps with instant messaging, chat, or voice call alerts, for example, generally need to open a network connection and make sure GCM delivers the message to the device without delay. Set high priority only if the message is time-critical and requires the user’s immediate interaction, and beware that setting your messages to high priority contributes more to battery drain compared to normal priority messages.
>
> **Normal priority:** This is the default priority for message delivery. Normal priority messages won't open network connections on a sleeping device, and their delivery may be delayed to conserve battery. For less time-sensitive messages, such as notifications of new email or other data to sync, choose normal delivery priority.

In my PHP when i want to send a notificacion I call this function:

```
function send_notification($con,$registatoin_ids,$idDestino,$titulo, $message, $nombreOrigenNotificacion, $dia, $mes, $anio, $idCancha, $idOrigen, $esComplejo) { 
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
    
    $fields = array(
        'data' =>array("idDestino" => $idDestino,"title" => $titulo,"message" => $message,"nombreOrigenNotificacion" => $nombreOrigenNotificacion,"dia" => $dia,"mes" => $mes,"anio" => $anio,"idCancha" => $idCancha,"idOrigen" => $idOrigen,"esComplejo" => $esComplejo),
        'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids
    );
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . apiKey,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    //echo $result;

  
}
```

**// EDIT:**
The GCM notification is between Android Phones

So..**How can I change the priority GCM message?**
Thanks

Comment: Sorry. But reading *The GCM notification is between Android Phones*, it gives the impression that you are sending the notification from one Android device to another Android device. I'm presuming this is a typo and you were pertaining that the GCM notification is sent to Android devices?

Comment: @intj the GCM notification is sent to Android Devices

Comment: I see. Have you tried adding `'priority' => 'high'` in the payload yet?

Comment: @Intj No, because I don't know how. The function send_notification is into my php

Comment: Are you successfully sending notifications already? Try adding it inside your `data` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You may add `$priority` parameter from within your function. As described in Code Reference - [**add_action**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) function

> **$priority**
>
> Used to specify the order in which the functions associated with a particular action are executed. Lower numbers correspond with earlier execution, and functions with the same priority are executed in the order in which they were added to the action.
>
> Default value: 10

Sample code found in [Generate Notifications From Your Web App With the Pushover API](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/generate-notifications-from-your-web-app-with-the-pushover-api--cms-22264) is shown below:

```
// send notification to admin mobile device via pushover
public function notify($device,$title='',$message='',$url='',$urlTitle='',$priority=1,$sound='gamelan',$debug=false) {
  if ($device['send_email']<>Device::SEND_EMAIL) {
    // load pushover key from Settings
    $setting = Setting::model()->getSettings();
    $po = new Pushover();
    $po->setToken($setting['pushover_app_api_token']);
    $po->setUser($device['pushover_user_key']);
    $po->setDevice($device['pushover_device']);
    $po->setSound($sound);
    $po->setTitle($title);
    $po->setMessage($message);
    if ($url<>'') {
      $po->setUrl($url);      
    }
    if ($urlTitle<>'') {
      $po->setUrlTitle($urlTitle);
    }
    $po->setPriority($priority);
    $po->setTimestamp(time());
    $po->setDebug(true);
    $go = $po->send();
    if ($debug) {
      echo '<pre>';
      print_r($go);
      echo '</pre>';      
    }      
  }
```

Comment: @teyams But i need to integrate the priority in my function